# Convert xslt 2.0 to xslt 1

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:data="urn:X-data"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsd data"
                version="2.0">

<data:convert>
  <convert old="RequestedLoans" new="RequestedLoan"/>
  <convert old="Companies" new="Company"/>
  ...add more here...
</data:convert>

<xsl:key name="converts" match="convert" use="@old"/>

<xsl:template match="*[key('converts',name(.),document(''))]">
  <xsl:element name="{key('converts',name(.),document(''))/@new}"
               namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which I need to use it in my application but since it is XSLT 2.0 I can not use it.
I was wondering if this can be translated to XSLT 1.0.
I have no knowledge of XSLT, please help me.

Comment: Which part of the XSLT does not work in your XSLT 1.0 processor? I am not completely into the differences. When you change `version="2.0"` to `version="1.0"` and try the XSLT, what errors do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a quick glance, the only XSLT 2.0 construct is the comma operator used twice in "@*, node()", which in this case can be safely replaced by the union operator "|".

Of course, the general task of converting XSLT 2.0 to XSLT 1.0 is possible in theory (both languages are Turing complete, therefore equivalent) but extremely difficult in practice. The conversion in this case only works because we know that "@*, node()" always delivers a sequence in document order.

The other caveat is that even though this conversion is easy, I find the idea of modifying code written in a language of which you have no knowledge pretty scary. It's a bit like trying to repair your gas boiler when you have no knowledge of how gas boilers work. I wouldn't want to be in the house when you attempt it.